# How can I trigger the hudson release build by time?

Tags: maven, ant, jenkins, hudson

In the hudson job configuration I only find the opportunity to trigger a time controlled build. But I am searching for a solution which enables me a time controlled release build.

Difference between "normal" build and Releasebuild in this case:
Build: Maven-Build, which generates artifacts
Releasebuild: Mavenbuild + pre-/post-build steps by ant

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "which enables me a time controlled release build" Do you mean it should timeout if it doesnt complete by 'X' amount of time?

Comment: No, I only want to automate the release build in order to start it each day by defined time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your "release" build does not follow CI principles, and actually performs another build (with pre/post steps, then why not create another job just for the release and set an appropriate timer?

Comment: I use the hudson releas plugin in order to define release steps, which include the ant tasks.

Comment: Yes, but this would only be a work around. Is there no API for the Hudson Release Plugin?

Comment: The plugin, by it's own definition, is for **manual** release builds: "`...executed when a manual release build is triggered...`", so what you are trying to do in the first place **is** a *workaround*. If you want automatic release builds (with extra pre/post steps), you should use either 2 jobs, or configure a single job with Conditional Build Step and Flexible Publish (that executes Conditional Build Step), where the conditions check for timer-based trigger and execute only in that case

Comment: You're right. Now I have it done without the release plugin.... Still in one hudson job, but inside the normal build cycle. Now the former release steps are normal build steps. Thank you for your hints!